# Postgressql - is it possible to make distinct on if the two values are true?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query, and i want to distinct by user id only if value id and type are the same:

```
SELECT DISTICT ON (us.id) us.id AS id en.type AS type
FROM enrollment AS en
INNER JOIN "user" AS us ON us.id = en.user_id
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add some sample data and an expected result?  It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: please add some data sample and expected results

Comment: Are you asking for `DISTINCT ON  (us.id, en.type)`?

Comment: @Bergi yes, worked in this way, thanks